# MMC and Server Manager Authentication Errors - Access Denied

Tags: remote-access, windows, hyper-v-server-2012

I'm trying to connect remotely from my Windows 8 client to manage my Hyper-V Server 2012. I have done everything I can find to configure remote management of the server including:

Added a net user on server

Enabled anonymous dcom access on server and client

Added firewall rules for "Windows Firewall Remote Management" and "Windows Management 
Instrumentation (WMI)" on server

Added firewall exception on server for client IP

Added cmdkey on client

Added server to TrustedHost list on client

Added LocalAccountTokenFilter policy registry entry on server

Added client IP to server's host file

Added server IP to client's host file

I cannot believe I am still getting these errors. What's even more strange is that I can connect in Hyper-V Manager and create VM's but not in MMC and Server Manager.

I also get Access Denied trying to Open the Authorization Store on my server from my client using Authorization Manager. I'm providing all the errors because I have a feeling they root from the same problem.

Does anybody see anything I missed?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I finally got this resolved.

on server:

net localgroup "Administrators" /add Admin

I don't understand why this is was not automatically included in hvremote.wsf ... It has a command that adds the Admin user to root\cimv2, root\virtualization, Distributed COM Users, and AZman Role Administrator Groups but doesn't add it to Administrators group.

EDIT: BTW my remote management setup is using Workgroups so the user and password MUST be the same on server and client